# How to include different menu for registered and unregistered users in php?

Tags: php, session

I need a little help with php. I'm trying to include different menus for registered and unregistered users.

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['user-class'] == 1) // 1 is class of registered users, which is assign after user log in
{echo '<a href="index.php?id=logout">Log out</a>'; }
else
{echo '<a href="index.php?id=login">Log in</a>'; }
?>
```

It works fine, but have one little problem: when the user is not logged in it gets a message
Notice: Undefined index: user-class

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use `if( isset( $_SESSION['user-class'] ) )`, which will check whether the variable exists yet. Alternatively, you can just predefine the `$_SESSION['user-class']` variable for all users, logged in or not, in your header files.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've called `session_start()` before you try to access any `$_SESSION` variables. And be aware that that index won't be set until you set it, you can check to see if its set using `isset()`: `if (isset($_SESSION['user-class']) && $_SESSION['user-class'] == 1) { ...`. Also, as a form of practice, don't name your `$_SESSION` variables with `-`, use `_` instead - makes it possible to use functions like `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user-class']) && $_SESSION['user-class'] == 1) {
   echo ' logout';
} else { 
   echo ' login';
}
```